# Scala 3 hello world imported, error when running sbt

Tags: java, scala, sbt, scala-3

i'm trying to get started with Scala 3.

When I follow the tutorial on: https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/getting-started.html. In terminal I can pull the hello_world project from github with:

```
sbt new scala/scala3.g8
```

Only when I run sbt in my newly created hello-world directory I get the error (see bottom).

Versions java jdk and sbt installed:
java version "16.0.1"
sbt script version: 1.4.9
*** edit based on question @Elliot
scala -version:
Scala code runner version 2.13.5

---

Any recommendations how to solver this problem?

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/reflect/internal/Trees
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at xsbt.boot.Pre$.xsbt$boot$Pre$$classMissing$1(Pre.scala:66)
    at xsbt.boot.Pre$$anonfun$getMissing$1.apply(Pre.scala:67)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$filter$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:264)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.RelativeUrlResolver.filter(RelativeUrlResolver.java:263)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.filter(Traversable.scala:105)
    at xsbt.boot.Pre$.getMissing$d83f809$4442e4c1(Pre.scala:67)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.checkLoader$2accd70c(Launch.scala:194)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.xsbt$boot$Launch$$provider$1(Launch.scala:272)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$xsbt$boot$Launch$$getScalaProvider0$2.apply(Launch.scala:275)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$xsbt$boot$Launch$$getScalaProvider0$2.apply(Launch.scala:274)
    at scala.Option.flatMap(Option.scala:170)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.xsbt$boot$Launch$$getScalaProvider0(Launch.scala:274)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anon$4.call(Launch.scala:263)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:47)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.locked(Launch.scala:261)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.getScalaProvider(Launch.scala:263)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$4.apply(Launch.scala:158)
    at xsbt.boot.Cache.newEntry(Cache.scala:16)
    at xsbt.boot.Cache.apply(Cache.scala:11)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.getScala(Launch.scala:146)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.getScala(Launch.scala:145)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.xsbt$boot$Launch$$getAppProvider0(Launch.scala:242)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anon$3.call(Launch.scala:205)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:95)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:80)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:99)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:60)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:50)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.locked(Launch.scala:261)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.app(Launch.scala:149)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.app(Launch.scala:147)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:104)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:37)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:120)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:20)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:56)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:18)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.reflect.internal.Trees
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 69 more
[error] [launcher] error during sbt launcher: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/reflect/internal/Trees
```

Comment: What is the result of `scala -version`?

Comment: Very relevant question: Scala code runner version 2.13.5

Comment: According to my knowledge sbt sets the version of Scala I want to run in a project, but i could be wrong obv. 
Upgrading with commands like.. : 
    cs install scala3-compiler or cs install scala3-repl
doesn't help me so far

Comment: https://www.scala-lang.org/download/scala3.html

Comment: I think that you need sbt 1.5.0 or higher.

Comment: yes you're right @insan-e. Unfortunately after updating sbt. To version sbt version: 1.5.1. I'm still struggling with the same error

Comment: Problem solved. With sbt version 1.5.1 I can succesfully pull the github project :)

There was some strange folder in my home directory that contained a sbt 1.4.x version, needed to delete that